# Will using ModRewrite cause the web page to refresh?

Tags: php, session, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am having an issue with my website which I have been a bit unsure of how to fix, only because it is not constant happening. Sometimes it does, and other times it does not.

The issue has to do with sessions, and redirecting. What I am doing is, when an user completes a task, they are redirected. When they are redirected, a $_SESSION is set with a message which says that what they did has been done. Once the page which the user is being redirected to loads, and the message is not being displayed, the session variable that contains the message is unset because the page refreshes before it is finally shown to the user. The weird thing is that for one specific redirect (when a user logs in with Facebook Connect) it works, but for all other redirects it does not.

My latest idea as to why this happens is because I am using mod_rewrite. Can mod_rewrite cause the page to refresh before it is displayed in the browser?

Here is the code which I am using for the URL rewriting:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L]
```

Comment: I dont think this has anything to do with mod_rewrite. Something else is happening, how are you clearing the session data? Surely the data should persist for the session until you specifically unset it.

Comment: You'll need to add some PHP code to show us what's going on. It sounds like you're not starting your session on the new page, or, possibly, something in your script that redirects is unsetting that variable after the redirect, if you aren't calling `exit` after the `header` function.

Comment: As it turns out adding exit after the header function fixed this issue. I wasn't aware of the fact that putting exit after the header was necessary. Thank you very much!

Comment: I went ahead and added that to my answer. Feel free to accept that as the answer. Glad I was able to help. As you might have guessed, I've dealt with the exact same problem before.

Answer (score 1):

No. mod_rewrite tells apache to take the incoming request that matches your rule (before a response has been sent to you), and route it to a particular destination. It's like mail forwarding--you don't get the letter twice, you just get it in a different location.

**UPDATING TO ADD SOLUTION**

You are likely performing some actions after the `header` call for the redirect. Add a call to `exit` after `header`, and your problem should be solved.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll continue looking for another solution.